# Prevent CKeditor from applying html escape entities via regex or between two chars

Tags: ckeditor

So I have a shortcodes system, i.e

```
[foo bar=1 foobar="2"]
```

Which will be edited via ckeditor.

How do I prevent CKeditor from escaping any entities within "[" and "]" ?

i.e, quotes resulting in ", spaces resulting in " ", as the result can be 
    [foo bar=1 foobar="2"]

Which naturally breaks the shortcode.

http://jsfiddle.net/h8wmbnn3/

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this that did not involve creating a widget?

Answer (score 1):

Like most of my answers nowdays... Can you post- and preprocess the content? If so that that string could be represented by a widget instead! It sounds like a really good fit for one.

So before loading content into CKE, convert for example `[foo x="1" y=2]` to `<div class="mywidget" data-type="foo" data-x="1" data-y="2">[something]</div>`. Then you will have your own custom made widget that, if necessary, can edit the X and Y and whatever else needs editing. Then after getting content from CKE / before saving it, convert `$('.mywidget')` back to a string!

Comment: Except the whole point that x=1 etc are user editable, without having to go into the source code.... that's the catch!

Comment: @Neokoenig yes indeed I was. With widgets, they can be editable in a very GUI/wysiwyg way :). It can have custom data editors, input field types and other such elegant features. It is a bit of work thoguh - that's the downside. The amount of work depends a lot on how your data is handled and what is the different possibilities and data source for for the attributes.

Comment: Yeah, it might work, but as you say, is a tonne of work (I've got potentially hundreds of variations on shortcodes where I'd need to have duplicate logic in the widget. Plus serverside ajax-y stuff to get data etc.)

Comment: You could simplify the widget by just making it be: <div class="shortcode" data-contents='[foo x="1" y="2"]'></div> and having 1 editable field for the whole shortcode.

Comment: @Lathan Very true! I think actually that some WordPress shortcode plugins do it similarly to your suggestion this because the shortcodes are just strings that can be edited in a widgety way. Personally I don't trust my users enough to provide a string that they have so much control over :).